# Configure dnsmasq and use DHCP provided DNS together

Tags: macos, dns, webserver

Running MacOX Sierra on MacBook Pro, and setting up for local dev environment with nginx as the web server, but I have a problem.

**What I want to do**

1. Use dnsmasq as the local dns server that returns `127.0.0.1` as the host for the wildcard domain `*.develop` (as .dev now clashes with ICANN).
2. Forward any unresolved requests to DNS servers provided by DHCP whenever I connect to a network so that I can resolve all other hostnames (external and internal.)

**Conditions and constraints**

1. I move between networks. My home network DHCP's the DNS server as `192.168.1.1`, but my work DHCP gives my DNS as `10.128.x.x`
2. The corporate network with the `10.128.x.x` DNS, also sets a `search domain` for internal addresses.
3. I'm in China, so just setting a bunch of public DNS servers like `Google or OpenDNS` as well as `127.0.0.1` may well work, but they're international and get throttled by GFW.

**What I've done so far**

1. I've installed `nginx` and `dnsmasq` using `homebrew`.
2. Services running using `sudo brew services start xxx`. )This is so I can run nginx on `port 80` and not `port 8080`.)
3. Set `dnsmasq` directive `address=/.develop/127.0.0.1`
4. I can verify that `dnsmasq` works, by using `dig`:

`dig testing.testing.one.two.three.develop @127.0.0.1`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> testing.testing.one.two.three.develop @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46013
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;testing.testing.one.two.three.develop. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
testing.testing.one.two.three.develop. 0 IN A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 20 12:04:44 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

4. Setting the DNS server to `127.0.0.1` in `Network Preferences` does work and I can 'ping' this it:

Ping example:

```
ping -c 1 this.is.a.test.develop
PING this.is.a.test.develop (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms

--- this.is.a.test.develop ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.036/0.036/0.036/0.000 ms
```

but then no external services are available because the only DNS available is my dnsmasq at `127.0.0.1`

**The problem**

1. It seems like the simple solution would be just to add `127.0.0.1` + `192.168.0.1` to my network adapter DNS list. That works at home, but not at the corporate location
2. Adding the corporate `10.128.x.x` would obviously work at the office, but then not at home
3. `So add both corporate and home DNS to the list?` This would then break any other wifi/ethernet connections because I would not pick up their DHCP DNS server
4. I cannot just add public DNS servers (like Google or Open DNS, because I'm in China. I need to have the DHCP supplied ones, as public DNS is very slow in China)

I'd like to know how others have solved what seems like a very frequent setup, but I'm having trouble.

I've already looked at two separate questions on stack exchange which have *similar problems* but not *identical*. The questions are attached to the bottom of this question [1], [2]. *What these questions show are that on macOS, `/etc/resolve.conf` has this notice:*

in the header

```
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
```

This suggests that *any modifications will not be read from this file, and other answers from the questions suggest that any files in `/etc/resolver/*` will also not be read*

So, my **real question is: is there any way to do:**

1. Always use 127.0.0.1 first
2. If not found use the dynamic DNS from whatever DHCP gives

**Why didn't you just use hosts?**

Becuase the idea of having a *.develop domain and then just adding a single site that uses regular expressions to dynamically resolve local sites is very attractive!

i.e. `some-sub-domain.develop` -> `/Users/myuser/www/some-sub-domain/`

[1] [dnsmasq not working on Mac OS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265530/dnsmasq-not-working-on-mac-os-sierra)

[2] https://serverfault.com/questions/478534/how-is-dns-lookup-configured-for-osx-mountain-lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found! For those looking to make this work, specifically in MacOS Sierra, the standard solution of using a resolver file in `/etc/resolver/*` actually works, without the need to change network preferences.

In my instance, where I wanted my local development domain name to be `*.develop`, I created a file called `develop` (no extension) with contents:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I thought this hadn't worked and that macOS does not read from these files, as I used the command `dscacheutil -flushcache` and it didn't work. Only a **hard restart** was enough to kick the system into using the local resolver.

For completeness, the content of my dnsmasq.conf file is:

```
no-resolv
address=/.develop/127.0.0.1
```